# how can I fix the error "Lighthouse returned error: NO_FCP." returned by "PageSpeed Insights" on my site "Wordpress" after install of a cache module

Tags: wordpress, caching, pagespeed-insights

I have just posted a Wordpress site with the Hoteller theme, I perform "PageSpeed Insights" tests but when I install a cache management plugin (WP Fast Cache, WP Super Cache, W3 Total Cache) without special configuration I find this error message.

> Lighthouse returned error: NO_FCP. Un problème est survenu lors de l'enregistrement de la trace du chargement de votre page. Veuillez relancer Lighthouse. (NO_FCP)

I do not really know where to look, it's annoying for me not to optimize this site, someone would have a track to give me?

Comment: If there is lighthouse plugin or theme deactivate it and possible then delete it and then try again.

Comment: thank you for your return, I have nothing that refers to "Lighthouse" in my project, this error appears when I activate a cache plugin provided by Wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was just a badly translated page that generated an infinite redirection loop

Comment: Hey @johan how did you figure out the issue. My WP site is not loading and failing with same error. Not able to figure our what exactly causing the failure.

Answer (score 1):

**NO_FCP** is a short-hand error code for 'No First Contentful Paint'.

'First Contentful Paint' is the first time something is drawn on the screen and is one of the criteria PSI uses to measure site performance.

This normally means something on the site is causing `Lighthouse` (the engine that powers Page Speed Insights) to fail to complete it's speed tests.

Try running the website through Lighthouse locally on your machine. (Developer tools in Google Chrome -> Audits tab and run audits.)

You will have to run it twice, once for desktop and once for mobile.

This may be different to a score that PSI would give as it depends on your connection but will still give you a good idea and recommendations on how to improve your score (plus there are 4 other audits you can run at the same time, which are a little bit useful to help you find other things to fix).

Answer (score 0):

i have faced this error when testing the page on Edge but when turned to chrome it worked fine